# How to create a Label in another screen using a Button in Kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy, label

I have this small issue where I'm trying to create a label in `LabelScreen` when a button in the `MenuScreen` is pressed. The closest I managed to do was making the Label appear in the same screen as the button.

The following code is just an simple example of what I would like to acheive. Any help is always appreciated!

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button,ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def Item1(self,button):
        App.get_running_app().cart += 5
        label1 = Label(text="Item 1: $5", font_size=25)
        self.add_widget(label1)

class LabelScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ExampleApp(App):
    cart = NumericProperty(0)
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

.kv

```
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<WindowManager>:
    MenuScreen:
    LabelScreen:

<MenuScreen>:
    name: "menu"

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Add to cart"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "y": 0.25}
            on_release:
                root.Item1(self)
        Label:
            text: "Cart: " + str(app.cart)
            font_size: 25
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "y": 0.25}
        Button:
            text: "Label Screen"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "y": 0.1}
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction = "left")
                app.root.current = "label"

<LabelScreen>:
    name: "label"

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "I want Item1 Label to appear here \n instead of in the MenuScreen"
            font_size: 25
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0.25}
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "y": 0.1}
            on_release:
                app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction = "right")
                app.root.current = "menu"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference the right screen window you want to add the wiget.

Since you are adding the widget whitin the python class first we have to get the app running, then we can navigate to the screen we want:

```py
def Item1(self,button):
    App.get_running_app().cart += 5
    label1 = Label(text="Item 1: $5", font_size=25)

    app_running = App.get_running_app()
    root_screen = app_running.root
    label_screen = root_scren.get_screen('label')
    label_screen.add_widget(label1)

    # Or simply:
    # App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('label').add_widget(label1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the help! Exactly what I was looking for